# Error Handling when no access to Visual Studio or application start point

Tags: c#, error-handling

I've recently joined a project where we are extending the functionality of an external application that our company has bought.

It is an Office Add-In with an admin console that allows you to create Windows Forms style forms with code-behind files, and gives you a single place to store common code. This can be quite challenging when implementing code that would be simple in a 'normal' Windows Forms application.

How do I implement global error handling so we can log all errors?

We aren't using Visual Studio and have no access to csproj files so we can't use IL weaving / AOP. We don't have access to the starting point of the application so we can't subscribe to thread or application unhandled exception events. I suspect this is already being subscribed to in the external code, as unhandled exceptions are exposed in a custom error message box by default.

I'm currently looking to see if we can extend the external dlls; however I don't see where I'm going to call our extended code.

The alternative is to go through every method and add a try/catch block in just to log errors, which makes my skin crawl! This project has been running for a year without dealing with error handling yet so it will also take a long time to implement this approach too.

Pseudo-Example class:

```
namespace Scriptlets
{
  using System;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  public partial class NewClient : FormScriptType
  {
    protected override void PageChanged(object sender, PageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeAddressLabels();
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show an example piece of code? Can you not define a base form class that contains logging and then inherit it from every new form and thus use the logger? If possible you can create the Forms as UserControls and add them to one form only, that has logging.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't inherit from a base form class, as the class declaration line is not editable in our editor either. I'm curious to how you would implement logging on the base class though. How would you add error handling to each method from a base class? I think our hands may be tied on this one.

Comment: About the logging - i thought of one method that takes a Func or Action and wraps the execution in a try/catch block: something like: public T ExecuteAndLogIfFail<T>(Func<T> action)
{
 try
 {         
  return action();
 }
 catch (Exception exception)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Implement your logger here: {0}", exception.Message);
 }
 return default(T);
} You can now wrap your new code into this and you will always have exception handling. Can't you trie something like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net) at least for the new code?

Comment: Usage of the code from the previous example: ExecuteAndLogIfFail<Boolean>(() =>
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Do something without output");
  return true;
 });
 var zero = 0;
 List<Int32> items = new List<Int32> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
 var result = ExecuteAndLogIfFail<Int32>(() =>
 {
  return items.Sum(i => i / 10);
 });
 Console.WriteLine(result);
 ExecuteAndLogIfFail<Boolean>(() =>
 {
  result /= zero;
  return true;
 });

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We tried Postsharp, but since we don't have access to the csproj files we can't get it to do it's thing unfortunately as that would have been brilliant. Your example code would be a good way of only having to write the catch block once. We'll still have to go back and modify all our methods, but it's a bit nicer than having try catch blocks everywhere, thanks!

Comment: Glad that the suggestion helped a bit. I though PostSharp could be somehow loaded at runtime. Last suggestion (if you haven't tried this already) would be to experiment with the [AppDomain.CurentDomain object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb506139.aspx) and hook the [unhandled exception event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx):AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
{
 Console.WriteLine("something happened ...");
}; .Maintaining closed legacy systems is PITA.

Comment: We don't have access to the starting point of the app, so we weren't able to subscribe to unhandled exceptions. Plus I discovered today by using dotPeek that they are putting the new window launch code in a try, catch block that catches all exceptions any window raises, so handling unhandled exceptions wouldn't actually catch anything. PITA indeed! I've learned a lot in the process though. If you want to add your comment as an answer about using methods with funcs, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! One last thing that i came up with (added into my answer) was modifying the assembly (inject IL code directly) where needed for example using [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) or some other tool. You don't need the project for this, because such tools can modify the executable directly. It could be an option. Good luck and all the best with the project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the logging - if you want to spare some typing of `try/catch` blocks, you could create one method that takes a `Func` or `Action` and wraps the execution in a `try/catch` block:

```
public T ExecuteAndLogIfFail<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    try
    {           
        return action();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implement your logger here: {0}", exception.Message);
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

You can now wrap your new code into this and you will always have exception handling.

Usage of the wrapper:

```
ExecuteAndLogIfFail<Boolean>(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do something without output");
    return true;
});

var zero = 0;
List<Int32> items = new List<Int32> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
var result = ExecuteAndLogIfFail<Int32>(() =>
{
    return items.Sum(i => i / 10);
});
Console.WriteLine(result);

ExecuteAndLogIfFail<Boolean>(() =>
{
    result /= zero; // catch and log!
    return true;
});
```

If you haven't tried this already you could experiment with the [AppDomain.CurentDomain object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb506139.aspx) and hook the [unhandled exception event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("something happened ...");
};
```

If you figured out, that the new window launch is wrapped in a `try/catch` block, you could try to modify (if this is ok) the assembly using [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) and add a `throw` statement into the `catch` block. I once used the [Reflexil Reflector plugin](http://reflexil.net/) to inject code into an assembly and save the modified executable - no app start points needed. The plugin site states, that it works with [Telerik's JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) too.

The conclusion is - maintaining closed legacy systems is PITA. :-)